# Simple app with timer is eating memory away?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, memory-management, timer

Can anybody explain why this tiny app's memory usage keeps increasing ?

```
static class Program
{
    private static System.Timers.Timer _TestTimer;

    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        _TestTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        _TestTimer.Interval = 30;
        _TestTimer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(_TestTimer_Elapsed);
        _TestTimer.Enabled = true;

        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }

    static void _TestTimer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        string test = "tick";
        Trace.WriteLine(test);
        test = null;
    }
}
```

Thanks!
Pika81

Comment: How fast are we talking here?

Comment: Also, does the memory usage stablizes/caps at a certain level?

Comment: @Greg - You know we also don't know what is going on in `Form1`.

Comment: @ChaosPandion: You're right. An empty _TestTimer_Elapsed handler still exhibits the same symptom. My new best guess is the new ElapsedEventArgs that are being created each time the event fires.

Comment: @theburningmonk: It starts at about 3.544k, after 10 mins it clocks in at 5.384k and stabilizes. I open DbgView to watch the traces, then suddenly jumps to 6.360k. Occasionaly, it drops a couple of bytes, but not a lot (4 to 16 bytes)

Comment: @ChaosPandion: Form1 is just the default form when creating a new Windows Forms app in Visual Studio. Empty form, nothing special.

Comment: @pika81 - can you try starting a new perfcounter as suggested in the article I included in my answer? that's likely to give you a better reading of how much memory your app is actually using as task manager tend to over-estimate the amount of memory used by a .Net app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion would be to crank up [Windbg](http://www.windbg.org/) and find out what objects exist in memory.
Agreed that we devs generally use it as the last option but in this case, it would give you the exact reason for the memory increase

Comment: I ran a profiler and GC runs after 5m30s and 14m14s. The string instances seem to get cleaned up. Task Manager is not trustworthy.

Answer (score 3):

You are assuming that the memory usage should not increase.  Wrong assumption, that's just *not* how either the .NET garbage collector or the Windows heap manager work.  Both of them work efficiently by using memory that's available for use instead of constantly releasing and reallocating memory.

Let it run for a week.  Might go quicker if you make the Interval smaller.  Also minimize the form for spectacular effects.

Answer (score 1):

I was digging through the source of `DefaultTraceListener` and I found this:

```
private void WriteLine(string message, bool useLogFile)
{
    if (base.NeedIndent)
    {
        this.WriteIndent();
    }
    this.Write(message + "\r\n", useLogFile);
    base.NeedIndent = true;
}
```

So the memory usage is probably growing too slowly for the GC to react immediately.

Answer (score 1):

If you're only looking at the Task Manager to see how much memory your process is using you're probably not getting a very accurate reading.

Have a read of this article:
http://www.itwriting.com/dotnetmem.php

It explains some of the shortfalls with using TaskManager as a means to measure the memory usage of your .Net application.